# Thread crashing when trying to join

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Update**

I did as recommended to create a `std::vector` of threads outside the scope, so I can `.join()` as soon as the thread has finished it's job, the problem now is that as soon as the thread is joined the program not exactly crashes, because it still runs in the background but the abort window appears. I checked if the thread was joinable and indeed it is when trying to join.

***Timer.cpp:***

```
void Timer::Start(int time, void(*lf)()) {
    slaveTimer = std::thread(&Timer::RunTimer, this, time, lf);
}

void Timer::RunTimer(int seconds, void(*lf)()) {
    auto time = (std::chrono::seconds)seconds;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(time);
    lf();

    slaveTimer.join();        //Program Crashes
}
```

***Main.cpp***

```
Timer timer1(10, [](){ std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; });
```

**Original Post**

I was trying to make coroutines with multithreading, the thing is that when I try to make the thread wait for X seconds, i then `thread.detach();` but that takes a couple of milliseconds and the screen (because I’m displaying with GL) freezes. One of the possible solutions that I can think of is making the thread detach itself before executing the action, but that doesn’t seem possible, so I was wondering if there is any way to do that or something similar to solve this problem.

Comment: Anyone who can see a few milliseconds has got some wicked eyeball-processing power.

Comment: Why do you need to pause the thread in order to call `detach()`?

Comment: @Galik i need to detach it and then pause it, so the sleep_for wont affect the other threads

Comment: Personally I would avoid detaching threads. I usually put them in a `std::vector<std::thread>` in a scope that is designed to outlive them.

Comment: @Galik And how do you get rid of them once their work is done without crashing the program?

Comment: @Aether You join them

Comment: @Galik I’m joining the thread as soon as it finishes and it crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186282/discussion-between-aether-and-galik).

Comment: I would strongly urge you to make a decision that either the thread will be detached (and manage its own lifetime) or joined (and the thing that joins it will manage its lifetime) and stick to that decision. Trying to split the difference makes needless complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call join from the function which is the body of execution thread. It will give you the error:

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)

> Error Conditions :
>   resource_deadlock_would_occur if this->get_id() ==
>   std::this_thread::get_id() (deadlock detected)

you need to add additional method for instance

```
void Timer::stop() {
  slaveTimer.join();
}
```

and call this method from thread which created `timer1` instance

```
Timer timer1(10, [](){ std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; });
timer1.stop();
```

or join thread in dtor of Timer:

```
Timer::~Timer() {
  slaveTimer.join();
}
```